# Kivy - Dispatching custom events to child widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I want to dispatch events from a `LayoutDemoApp` to a child widget. The goal is to have a websocket listener dispatch events, allowing any widget to listen to them (e.g. updating labels and so forth). I am probably misunderstanding how events works here and the Kivy examples. Is the `register_event_type` simply local to the `LayoutDemoApp` object, and this not possible?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.bind(on_foo=self.on_foo)

    def on_foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("MyButton.on_foo")


class LayoutDemoApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type("on_foo")

    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        r1 = BoxLayout()
        
        button12 = MyButton(text='B1')
        button12.bind(on_press=self.on_bar)

        r1.add_widget(button12)
        root.add_widget(r1)
        return root

    def on_bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("LayoutDemoApp.on_bar")
        self.dispatch("on_foo")
    
    def on_foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LayoutDemoApp().run()
```

Comment: If `on_foo` is an event belong to `MyButton` it must be registered there with default handler.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `dispatch_children` method on the root layout rather than the App itself and registering the event within the target widget as suggested by @ApuCoder should give the desired result.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type("on_foo")

    def on_foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (caller,) = args
        print(f"{self.text}'s on_foo called by {caller}")


class LayoutDemoApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        r1 = BoxLayout()

        button1 = MyButton(text="B1")
        button1.bind(on_press=self.on_bar)
        button2 = MyButton(text="B2")
        button2.bind(on_press=self.on_bar)

        r1.add_widget(button1)
        r1.add_widget(button2)
        root.add_widget(r1)
        return root

    def on_bar(self, instance):
        print("LayoutDemoApp.on_bar")
        self.root.dispatch_children("on_foo", instance.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = LayoutDemoApp().run()
```